# Create plugin/function to catch XML-data via Shortcode

Tags: shortcode, xml, http-api

I need to display data from an XML-file inside Wordpress posts, and I want to use shortcodes to do it. 
I have this XML-file witch I need to get the data from;

> ```
> http://xml.prisguide.no/productExport.php?productId=151690
> ```

I would like to have a shortcode e.g. `[prisguide id="151690"]`, and then the product information (limited to name, price, basic information etc) from the XML-file will display in the post.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please show us your research effort about the shortcode (how you actually use it).

Comment: By itself this is mostly just PHP programming issue. Please elaborate which specifics parts of this task you need help implementing in WordPress and what you have already working.

Answer (score 1):

If this file is remotely available to you, then you should be using the HTTP API.

```
$response = wp_remote_request(
     'http://xml.prisguide.no/productExport.php?productId=151690'
    ,array(
        'ssl_verify' => true // If the request isn't working, try it with `false`
     )
);
```

You then simply go and catch the response and check if it's an error:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) )
    // don't expose error to other users than admin
    return current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ? $response->get_error_message() : '';
```

Then you go and extract the content.

```
$content = trim( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
$content = new SimpleXMLElement( $content );
```

Now do whatever you need with your retrieved data.